# Upgrade to 16.04 fails

Tags: upgrade

I have an Ubuntu VM (running in VMWare Fusion) and I can no longer update my apps - software updater tells me I must update from 15.10

When I try to Upgrade the machine does nothing - I never see any upgrade happen and I seem to be stuck on 15.10

[This is the window I am responding to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1ND4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend doing the upgrade from the console, so you can see the output.

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And see if there are any errors in the terminal.

Comment: I get a hang after a bunch of messages like this:

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages

Comment: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse Sources                                                               
                                                                                                                                   
99% [Waiting for headers]

Comment: Try a different mirror then.